# EVAL: undefined function DEFINE

Tags: lisp, clisp

I've written a very simple program:

```
(define size 2)

(print size)
```

When I run this code, I get following error:

```
*** - EVAL: undefined function DEFINE
```

What does the error mean? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 11):

`define` is not a part of the ANSI Common Lisp language which is implemented by GNU CLISP (I think you are confusing CL with Scheme).

When defining a variable, use [`defvar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm),
for a function use [`defun`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defun.htm).

You might want to get a book, e.g., [ANSI Common Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/acl.html).

Answer (score 2):

**define** in the Scheme programming language means defining a variable or a function,
**defvar** or **defparameter** in the Common Lisp programming language (which is what CLISP implements, and which is different from Scheme) means defining a variable.
**defun** in Common Lisp means defining a function.

```
CL-USER 195 > (defparameter size 2)
SIZE

CL-USER 196 > (print size)

2 
2
```